# Does system restore delete videos downloaded?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

Does system restore delete my YouTube videos downloaded?

I am thinking to make a system restore. I am not familiar to system restore.

Answer (score 2):

Your files are safe.

System Restore can make changes to Windows system files, registry settings, and programs installed on your computer. It also can make changes to scripts, batch files, and other types of executable files on your computer. Personal files, such as documents, e‑mail, photos, and music files, are not changed.

Review the documentation here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/what-types-of-files-does-system-restore-change

Comment: I forgot to mention . I am using Win 7 SP-1 64bit version.

Comment: Still safe. asdf

Comment: Only a factory reset or format runs high chance /risk of loss

Comment: Yep. Nice comment @linuxdev2013. If the content is on an internal hard drive native to the system (laptop or desktop), it will get blown away with a factory reset. Even if you purchased a machine from Dell (or whoever) with additional hard drives, don't trust the reset not to format them. Just don't.

Comment: @linuxdev2013 That's not really an accurate statement,obviously there are other causes of data loss like a delete command,u might have heard of `rm` given your username, so you're technically very obviously wrong.n alex was good in stating what can be lost with a system restore(yes, high risk),even programs on the desktop can go from a system restore.Try reading what alex wrote before you, it's more accurate than anything you said. What alex said seems right to me. And nobody suggested that formatting wouldn't involve data loss.U r just kind of stating the obvious but in a very inaccurate way

Answer (score 0):

Relax. Windows system restore only restores the programs files, updates and such details which  are related to running the system. Videos and other files which donot affect the working of the system or which was not installed will not be deleted.So you can surely restore your Pc without the fear of losing your downloaded videos.